# What is wrong with this CFIF structure?

Tags: coldfusion, sessionid

I have the following at the top of a page...

```
<cfif isdefined("session.loggedin") and session.loggedin eq true>

    <cfinclude template="includeUserInfo.cfm">

    <cfinclude template="includeSideBar.cfm">

<cfelse>

    <cflocation url="../sign-in.cfm">

</cfif>
```

When I execute the page and session.loggedin DOES equal true it executes as expected and adds the included files.

If I hit the page without logging in - I'm not being redirected to the sign in page - I'm just getting a completely blank page - zero html in the view source.

Session management is enabled in my application.cfc file

I'm not sure if what I am doing is wrong - appreciate any advice.

Comment: cflocation performs a HTTP redirect, so check the browser debug tools to see what is happening, specifically, the "Net" tab - you may need to use the "persist" option to ensure the request is displayed. (My guess is it wants an absolute URL instead of the relative one you currently have.)

Comment: Also, your if statement should really be `<cfif StructKeyExists(session,'loggedin') and session.loggedin>`

Comment: Replace the cflocation tag with some static text that tells you that you are in the cfelse block.  This is for troubleshooting only.

Comment: Can you hit `../sign-in.cfm` on its own?

Comment: what does your url say? Is it trying to get to the right place?

Comment: Hi Matt - the url is hitting the page with cfif block included; Thanks

Comment: Hi James - yes I can hit the sign-in.cfm page on its own with no issues - and it functions fine. Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter - amended the cfif statement as suggested. Also checked the debug console to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dan - thanks great suggestion. It looks like I'm not in the CFIF block - the dummy text I added is also not showing at all. Opens a new line of enquiry. Thanks

Comment: so if you're not getting into your else statement that is your issue. You need to determine why the value still exists in session. fyi you can use @ then type a users name to notify them of your message

Comment: can you add a screenshot of a `<cfdump var="#session#">` before you try to login, and after you try to login?

Comment: @MattBusche - Hey Matt, thanks for the tip about user notification. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JamesMohler - Hi James, when I am logged in the dump shows loggedin true, a session ID, URL tokens and the username - after log out it shows the seesion ID and URL tokens - but no loggedin value or user name. - so I think the log in and log out is functioning as I'd expect. 

Not sure what to make of the completely blank file when trying to access a page that renders fine when logged in and should bump me to the log in page when I try to access it without logging in. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I didn't say console - I said the net/network tab. If the cflocation is occurring there _will_ be a HTTP 302 response in there, telling you where the browser is trying to go next. It may or not be where you expect it to. (And if the cflocation is _not_ occurring, the net tab will confirm that, and can provide other potentially useful info to help with debugging.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBoughton - I dod look at the net tab, shouldn't have referred to the console tab - but I was looking at all of them. The net tab shows only the page that the cfif is on - no attempt to go to the next step.

Comment: In that case, check the logs (in {cfusion}/logs dir) for any suppressed errors that might be occurring - sort by modified date (and if this is Windows, make sure it _is_ modified date, not just "date") and check the end of any recently modified files for any potentially relevant messages.

Comment: @Simon - in your reply above to Dan did you mean that it does not appear as though your code is even getting into the cfelse block?

Comment: Hi @Miguel-F, yes it looks to me like the cfif block is not being reached - but only when trying to access the page without being logged  in - when logged in everything seems to work as I'd expect. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so (as is often the case) I had missed the underlying cause of the problem - and while focussing on the imagined problem with the CFIF statement itself, missed the small cfinvoke that was before it in the code. That was trying to execute a database lookup, but failing when a user was not logged in.

swapping these around and making sure the block above is before everything else on the page has done the trick. Go me. Thanks everyone for the input.